# Elasticsearch wildcard support in field name with queries and filters

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch supports wildcards in field name with multi-match query and Query String Query as described [in here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). However, it doesn't support the same with match query. Are there any other queries / filters where it does support wildcards in field names? If not, is there any performance consideration related reason its not supported?

Comment: May be this question is for elasticsearch user group